# Why I can't uses proteced method? Error: "'void A::printToScreen() const' is protected"

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, protected

given the following code:

```
class A {
protected:
    void printToScreen() const;
public:
    A() = default;
    virtual ~A() {
    }
    virtual void Print(const A& a) const=0;
};

void A::printToScreen() const {
    std::cout << "printToScreen" << std::endl;
}

class B: public A {
public:
    B() = default;
    void Print(const A& a) const override;
};

void B::Print(const A& a) const {
    std::cout << "Print_B" << std::endl;
    a.printToScreen(); // *****error*****
}
```

And for example:

```
A* a = new B();
    a->Print(*a);
```

I get the following error:

> 'void A::printToScreen() const' is protected

But I don't understand what it's not correct in my code. `printToScreen` is protected, but, I uses this method In a class inherited from A , so what it's the problem?

In addition, what is the different between `this->printToScreen();` to `a->printToScreen();` ? it's seen same (while I talking about the access to protected methods)

---

How can I fix it? According to the linked answer it's still gives me error, because I can't write like that in `class B` :
 `void Print(const B& a) const override;`
The argument must be from type `A` - like in `class A` (for the override)

Comment: I edited my question..

Comment: shouldn't you implement A::print and make A::printToScreen the pure virtual function that is reimplemented in B? I do not understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: Normally, your virtual method would print itself (this), not an argument. Protected only gives visibility through **this**. Realistically, to do what you appear to be trying to do, you would want a B::PrintToScreen() method.